# Guardar datos usando un struct

Tags: c

Quiero guardar los tiempos de los atletas en minutos y segundos. Para eso, hice un struct de tiempo. Pero tengo dos problemas:

1. Me queda guardado solamente el último dato ingresado.
2. Cuando le pido que controle que el usuario no ingrese más de 59 minutos, ni segundos, me salta del programa. Pongo: if (tiempo.minutos < 60 && tiempo.segundos < 60).

Les muestro el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct time{
  int minutos;
  int segundos;
}tiempo;


int main(){

int atleta [10];
int i=0;



for (i=0;i<10;i++){
  printf ("\nEscriba el tiempo del atleta [%d]:\n ", i+1);
  printf ("Minutos: ");
  scanf ("%d", &tiempo.minutos);
  printf ("\n Segundos: ");
  scanf ("%d", &tiempo.segundos);
}

for (i=0;i<10;i++){
  printf ("\n Tiempo atleta [%d]: ", i+1);
  printf ("%d", tiempo.minutos);
  printf (" minutos y %d segundos.\n", tiempo.segundos);
}

}
```

Comment: Tú dices: *Me queda guardado solamente el último dato ingresado.*, pero si solo estas creando un dato time llamado tiempo ¿Cómo quieres que guarde los demas datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas cargando 1 solo struct y lo pisas 10 veces, deberías crear un array de tu struct y recorrer uno por uno.

```
struct time{
  int minutos;
  int segundos;
};

struct time tiempos[10];

int main(){
```

y luego cargarlos / consultarlos dentro del for

```
 scanf ("%d", &tiempos[i].minutos);
```

Comment: Es cierto, por eso me guardaba solo el último, necesitaba un array en tiempo. Ahora, cuál es el problema de mi if?

Comment: ..... ¿Cual If?

Comment: if (tiempo.minutos < 60 && tiempo.segundos < 60). cuando lo uso me salta fuera del programa

Comment: if (tiempo[i].minutos < 60 && tiempo[i].segundos < 60)

Comment: estando dentro del for

Comment: Adentro del for. Ahora lo probé y sigue dando error: 
for (i=0;i<10;i++){

    if (tiempo[i].minutos < 60 && tiempo[i].segundos < 60){
        printf ("\nEscriba el tiempo del atleta [%d]:\n ", i+1);
        printf ("Minutos: ");
        scanf ("%d", &tiempo[i].minutos);
        printf ("\n Segundos: ");
        scanf ("%d", &tiempo[i].segundos);
    }
    else printf ("Escriba un número menor a 59.\n");
}

Comment: si tu array se llama time tiempos[10]; tienes que reemplazar  todos los tiempo[i] por  tiempos[i]

Comment: mi array se llama tiempo, por eso lo mantuve